# Why is there no x or y axis shown on this d3 chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 chart as follows.

HTML:

```
<svg></svg>
```

JS:

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
width = 960,
height = 500;

var startOfWeek = moment().startOf("week").toDate();
var endOfWeek = moment().endOf("week").toDate();

var dxSyncEvents = [];
var now = moment();

var times = [];
var sites = [];

/*
Some stuff that pushes JS Date objects onto times[] and strings onto sites[]
*/

var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([startOfWeek, endOfWeek]).range([0, 960]);
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(sites).rangePoints(500, 10);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.hours, 12)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'))
    .tickSize(8)
    .tickPadding(8);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(times)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", "10px")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("cx", xScale)
    .attr("cy", yScale)
    .call(xAxis)
    .call(yAxis);
```

Why is it that I don't get any axes on the chart? Can't see them on the screen and can't see them in the DOM in the developer tools. I do see some circles, however.

There are some console errors that don't offer much help:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M-6,undefinedH0VundefinedH-6" 
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(0,NaN)" (twice)
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling your xAxis and yAxis objects on the result of your .enter().append("circle") call, which will create a circle element for each new data elements in times.  I suspect that is not what you want.  You probably want to append a g element for each axis and perform the .call(xAxis) and .call(yAxis) on those.  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 is a simple line chart that might help?

Comment: What Ben said. Also it looks like you are not passing in the right data structure for rangepoints. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangePoints

Comment: @BenLyall, please use an answer rather than a comment and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're calling your `xAxis` and `yAxis` objects on the result of your `.enter().append("circle")` call, which will create a `circle` element for each new data element in `times`.

I suspect that is not what you want. You probably want to append a `g` element for each axis and perform the `.call(xAxis)` and `.call(yAxis)` on those.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 is a simple line chart that might help.